# Object hierarchy vs. "case" statements

Tags: architecture, oop

Consider a web form with a dropdown.  Based on the selection in the dropdown, some options are displayed - not many, say two or three for each selection.  When the user clicks OK, the server creates a new object, type determined by the dropdown, attributes from the appropriate options.

So the server has to do three things based on the dropdown selection: display some data; retrieve some data, and create an object of the appropriate type.  Would you use three case statements here, or build an AObjectCreator class that can be appropriately subclassed for each selection in the dropdown?

Comment: I like the, when is it feasible to subclass or use more advanced design patterns versus simply a few cases, part of the question.

Comment: It depends on whether you expect more types to be added in the future. If the number of types will most probably not change ever and is small enough, go switch case it in one place - have a factory method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).
Take a look at the now almost synonymous PizzaFactory example

Comment: Would you really create a factory, a base class, and two subtypes if your dropdown only had two options?

Comment: No. In that case, I'd just use an if-else and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass.

Switch statements can get messy, fast.

Comment: How fast?  Would you go to the trouble if there were 5 options in the dropdown?  How about 3?  2?

Comment: There's no formula. If there's a potential to add more options, go with objects. If cases can be complex, go with objects. Ultimately the design is up to you. Do what fit's your problem best. Subclassing is only my suggestion.